# Why is tail not working here?

Tags: linux, bash, csh

My csh script

```
#!/bin/csh
# C-schell script to increase the boundingbox....

echo '%\!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0'
echo '%%BoundingBox: 0 0 1100 1100'
tail +3 $argv[1]
```

Called here

```
csh bbox.csh plt >! plt_P1.ps
```

But I have

```
csh -f bbox.csh plt
tail: cannot open ‘+3’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

What is `tail` supposed to do?The guy who wrote the code uses Darwin,I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Use `tail -n+3 ...` . The form without `-n` has been deprecated for decades and not all `tail` implementations still allow it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**GNU tail** does not support this syntax. Use `tail -n +3 "$argv[1]"` instead.

If you are using e.g. bash, dash or zsh as shell:
you need also to modify the `>!` to `>` in the command line:

```
csh bbox.csh plt > plt_P1.ps
```

Comment: @jofel Works fine!But csh bbox.csh plt >! plt_P1.ps,how should I change >! for ubuntu?Bash scripting is differnet in Darwin.

Comment: Just use `>` instead of  `>!`.

Answer (score 1):

Tail prints the last 10 (by default) lines of the file. Use -n option for more lines.